# how to change language in facebook integration in ios?

Tags: ios, facebook, internationalization

I am developing an app in which I have integrated facebook login, now I want to change the language of facebook login dialog from english(U.S.) to spanish.I have attached the image of the login dialog.[image] Can anybody tell me that how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Search for facebook.com URL in your project scope (Facebook Login Dialog class may be) and append the url with: `&locale=en_US`